# Alternatives to scipy.integrate

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, numerical-integration, numerical-computing

I'm new to numerical integration with Python and I was wandering what is the best Python package for this purpose. Of course I discovered [`scipy.integrate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) that is pretty nice, but I wanted to know if that is really the "gold stardand" or if there are better alternatives around.

Can sombody give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `numpy` is the most widely used numeric extension, and `scipy` its main extension for specialty things this. No governing body has issued  standards.

Comment: https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy (authored by myself)